# Is there an English version of the Ruby Hacking Guide?

Tags: ruby

As far as I can tell, a complete English translation of the [*Ruby Hacking Guide*](http://i.loveruby.net/ja/rhg/book/) does not exist. I find this unbelievable given the fact that it was originally written in *2004*. Of course, a few attempts have been made:

- The [RubyForge project](http://rhg.rubyforge.org/) is ostensibly the most official, but even a cursory look through the [mailing list archives](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rhg-discussion/) reveals that [it has low traffic](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rhg-discussion/2011-January/000211.html) and [is more or less dead](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rhg-discussion/2010-May/000206.html).
- [C. E. Thornton](http://hawthorne-press.com/) also took a stab at translating it, calling his version the [*Integrated Ruby Hacker's Guide*](http://edwinmeyer.com/Release_Integrated_RHG_09_10_2008/index.html). While substantial, it too is incomplete: the "blue" chapters are machine translated.

[This site](http://www.edwinmeyer.com/Integrated_RHG.html) gives the most thorough background that I could find.

My questions are as follows.

1. Does anyone know if there is another significant English translation of the *Ruby Hacking Guide* available?
2. Is there an active translation effort in progress?
3. Even if someone were to produce an English version of the *Ruby Hacking Guide*, would it still be relevant?
4. Apart from the *Ruby Hacking Guide*, what is the best resource for English-speaking developers who want to work on/understand Ruby internals?

Comment: Don't know, but I'd question it's relevance anyway, given that it is so old. There have been some pretty major changes to Ruby since then.

Comment: Hm, it looks like two people have voted to close this question as "not constructive" and "not a real question." Should I have asked this on Programmers instead? Is StackOverflow not the appropriate place to discuss code documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The most important stuff is already translated in your links. Ruby has changed a lot since 2004, especially with 1.9. It would be better to write a new Ruby Hacking Guide instead of translating the old one.
2. I read a lot of books about Ruby but the Dave Thomas' screencast was by far the best on understanding the ruby fundamentals.
   http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming

There is always the option to read the original source code of Ruby. A good alternative is the source code of http://rubini.us/ as most of it is already in Ruby.

Comment: Do you know if Rubinius is going to replace the current Ruby virtual machine, or if it's going to remain an alternative?

Comment: Rubinius will not replace the current Ruby (Matz Ruby) for several reasons. It is way slower on comparison with jRuby and Matz Ruby. Furthermore it is not stable AFAIK, you should not use it in production environments as many gems do not work. IMHO jRuby is the only alternative. If you have Java installed jRuby is notihng more then a new .jar and you can use Java libraries. Still Matz Ruby is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io had its translation completed in [September 2013](https://twitter.com/mineroaoki/status/384462337773555712).

The site is based on https://github.com/ruby-hacking-guide/ruby-hacking-guide.github.com . Some minor changes have been made since September 2013.